# Android GPS accuracy distance measurement

Tags: android, gps

I'm pretty new to Java & Android and I have some issues with a code.

Does the `location1.distanceTo(location2)` method calculates the distance considering elevation changes too?

Another issue is that although I'm not moving the device, the distance measured changes.
This is the code I have:

```
public class GpsCalculator{
public Activity activity;
private LocationManager locationManager = null;
private Location previousLocation = null;
private double totalDistance = 0D;
private Context context;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 1 meter
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000; // 1 second
TextView distance_tracker;

public GpsCalculator(TextView dt) {
    distance_tracker = dt;
}


public void run(Context act){
    context = act;
    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Add new listeners with the given params
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener); // Network location
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener); // Gps location
}

public void stop(){
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation){
        if (previousLocation != null){
            GpsCalculator.this.totalDistance +=  previousLocation.distanceTo(newLocation);
        }

        // Update stored location
        GpsCalculator.this.previousLocation = newLocation;

        CharSequence text = Double.toString(totalDistance);
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        distance_tracker.setText(df.format(totalDistance)+ " m");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}; }
```

I'd like to mention that the accuracy issues persisted with or without the network provider listener.

**Conclusion**

The code is correct, but the accuracy of GPS data isn't. I understood this from the comments under Carsten's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location object normally also contains altitude  information so elevation is taken into account.

Does the location change between updates? I would think so because it is updated every sec in your case.

Comment: Well then, how should I optimize the code so if I don't move, the distance won't change?

Comment: I would stick to the GPS provider, increase MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES and also increase MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES. As you might also get updates from other sources in between it is also worth to verify yourself if the distance between the last update and the new one is big enough for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that the GPS satellites' accuracy is not to 1 meter. I'm doing it for outdoor activities, so I guess I'll take the bike and ride a bit :)